# "expected declaration specifiers" error message

Tags: c, file-io

I'm currently learning the C language in college so this is a homework assignment but I have a small problem. I'm guessing I've just misjudged the syntax or are missing something really obvious. My compiler is telling me that there is:

> expected declaration specifiers or "..." before constant

and pointing to the `O_RDWR`.

I've googled and searched on Stack Exchange but there doesn't seem anything specific to it. Following the syntax in a C reference it's fine. I've looked around and it says I have not predefined the typedef but I've tried that to no avail.

I've starred the section that is causing the problem according to the compiler with `**`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int count;

    printf ("This program was called  \"%s\".\n",argv[0]);

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        for (count = 1; count < argc; count++)
        {
            printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", count, argv[count]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The command had no arguments.\n");
    }

    if  (argc == 4)
    {
        printf("There are the correct number of arguments(4)");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not enough arguments! please try again");
    }

    **int open(const char *argv[1], O_RDWR);

    return 0;**
}
```

Comment: +1: I wish all the new user homework questions were like this. (Although the indentation needs a little cleanup.)

Comment: As an aside: if you're going to do regular file input / output in an introductory C course, I think you're looking for [`fopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) instead of `open()`. The former is a standard library function, the latter is a low-level system call.

Comment: This is for an operating systems course, the whole idea is using low level system calls. It's rather perplexing, I'm an international student from the UK and have had to take up graduate courses! It's pretty intense but with the help of you lot and the internet I'm doing alright!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int open(const char *argv[1], O_RDWR);
```

What are you trying to do by this statement? Compiler treats this as **function declaration**, not function call. And it fails because O_RDWR is not a type name. If you need to call [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/open.html), syntax shall be like this:

```
int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
if(fd != -1)
{
   // File opened OK. Proceed with file operations.
}
else
{
   // File failed to open. Handle error occured
}
```

Comment: right so I'm using this to open a file that I'm going to read some text from, create a file and write the text to the output file. I need it to return something so I can do error checking. Hence why I used int.

Comment: @TimothyFord What you wrote would declare a new function called `open()`. If you want to store the return value of the existing system call, you need to do `int result = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've got going now, then for the error checking using if the returned number is <1 then it's and error!

Comment: @TimothyFord `open` can validly return 0. An error is indicated by a negative value -- check your POSIX documentation. But also consider using `fopen` from stdio ... I doubt that you really need or want `open`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `open(argv[1], O_RDWR);` - you don't need to specify the arg's type or the return value.

... and I'm assuming the **'s are just to highlight the problem area - if not, they should go too... edit: just noticed you said that in the question!

Answer (score 0):

The **open** call returns a **HANDLE** to the specified file of type **int**. So you only have to declare an **int** type **HANDLE** to collect from **open**. So,

```
int FileDesc ;
FileDesc = open( argv[1], O_RDWRD ) ;
// Check for Errors here
```